# Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. > Failed to obtain compression information for entry

Tags: android, opencv, gradle, dl4j

I'm getting this error while building my app. I couldn't find any relevant posts about this error...

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. > Failed to obtain compression information for entry
```

Top-level gradle:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'



   // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {url "C://Users/yuh5/.m2/repository"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be running out of memory for me. Using the [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47689687/5532491) fixed my issue.