# com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Element type is invalid

Tags: java, react-native, crash, logcat

### TL;DR

Non-Expo React Native app 0.63 builds and runs perfectly on device "debug" variant, but when changing to "release" variant it crashes with absolutely no errors thrown at metro, instead only showing a shady exception stack:

#### Steps to facepalm hard

- `react-native run android --variant="debug"` -> Works
- `./gradlew clean`
- `react-native run android --variant="release"` -> Stops working
- `./gradlew clean`
- `react-native run android --variant="debug"` -> Works Again

### logcat

```sh
adb logcat AndroidRuntime:V *:S

--------- beginning of main
01-04 22:04:26.538 18552 18552 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
01-04 22:04:57.786 18552 18552 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
01-04 22:04:59.513 18630 18630 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-04 22:04:59.525 18630 18630 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
01-04 22:04:59.771 18630 18630 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
01-04 22:04:59.858 18630 18630 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.trique.app, PID: 18675
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: 
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: This error is located at:
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in k
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in O
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in b
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in w
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTScrollView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in y
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in ScrollView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in x
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in k
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in PanGestureHandler
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in k
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in G
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in w
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in h
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in GestureHandlerRootView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in G
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in p
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in c
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Portal.Host
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in E
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in c
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RNCSafeAreaView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in Unknown
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:     in C, stack:
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: Xl@93:86688
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@93:36589
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: jr@93:46349
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: Ci@93:81373
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: Cl@93:75314
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: Rl@93:75239
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: Pl@93:75006
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: Tl@93:72139
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: Tl@-1
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@93:24153
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: unstable_runWithPriority@202:3882
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: an@93:24100
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: ln@93:24035
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: xe@93:89844
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: Ee@93:12419
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: Re@93:12808
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: receiveEvent@93:13217
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: value@27:3350
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@27:747
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: value@27:2610
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: value@27:719
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: value@-1
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime: 
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
01-04 22:05:04.076 18675 18695 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

#### RN Info

```
⟩ react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: Linux 4.19 Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 10 (buster)
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3240 CPU @ 3.40GHz
    Memory: 846.02 MB / 11.68 GB
    Shell: 3.0.2 - /usr/bin/fish
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.5 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.12.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 26, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 26.0.3, 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 30.0.0
      System Images: android-26 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_232 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: Not Found
    react-native: 0.63.2 => 0.63.2 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

#### gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true

# (Pra3t05) Increased JVM Heap size @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208618/execution-of-compression-failed-error-when-building-project-in-android-studio
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M

# Version of flipper SDK to use with React Native
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.37.0
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=my-upload-key.keystore
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=app-key
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=password
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=password
```

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: 'packages/mobile/index.js',
        root: '../../../../',
        enableHermes: false,
]
apply from: '../../../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle'
// project.ext.vectoricons = [
//     iconFontNames: [ 'Ionicons.ttf' ]
// ]
// apply from: "../../../../node_modules/@ovaeasy/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontsDir: '../../../..',
    iconFontNames: [
        'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Ionicons.ttf',
        'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.tts',
        'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/FontAwesome.tts',
        'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf',
        'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Octicons.ttf',
    // 'packages/components/src/libs/vector-icons/fonts/octicons2/generated/Octicons2.ttf'
    ],
]
apply from: '../../../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle'
/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get('enableHermes', false)

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.trique.app'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    // dexOptions {
    //     javaMaxHeapSize '4g'
    // }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ['armeabi-v7a': 1, 'x86': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'x86_64': 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'  // From node_modules

    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }
    implementation(project(':react-native-google-signin'))
    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = '../../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/'
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + 'hermes-debug.aar')
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + 'hermes-release.aar')
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file('../../../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle'); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Do any of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/34130539/18157, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796281/18157,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/44897070/18157

Comment: No, the problem was a very specific issue of a third party library that parsed svg assets, check my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In Short

Disable obfuscation caused by minified javascript, updating the android `build.gradle` like this:

```
project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: 'packages/mobile/index.js',
        root: '../../../../',
        enableHermes: false,
        extraPackagerArgs: [ '--minify=false' ], //Add this!
]
```

And then clean the android project by using `./gradlew clean`, and after having deployed the app to a device run:

```sh
adb logcat AndroidRuntime:V *:S
```

And open the app, errors will be correctly logged in.

#### For the record

The problem was related to [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg#problems-with-proguard), as the previously obfuscated error reveals:

```sh
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.trique.app, PID: 22500
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: 
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: This error is located at:
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in Icons
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in AnimatedComponent
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in TouchableOpacity
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in GoogleSigninButton
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in KeyboardAvoidingView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTScrollView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in ScrollView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in ScrollView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in LoginScreen
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in StaticContainer
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in StaticContainer
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in EnsureSingleNavigator
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in SceneView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef(CardSheet)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in AnimatedComponent
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in PanGestureHandler
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in PanGestureHandler
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in AnimatedComponent
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in Card
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in CardContainer
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in MaybeScreen
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in MaybeScreenContainer
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in CardStack
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in KeyboardManager
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in SafeAreaProviderCompat
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in GestureHandlerRootView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in GestureHandlerRootView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in StackView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in StackNavigator
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in AuthStack
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in EnsureSingleNavigator
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in ThemeProvider
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RootNavigator
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in ThemeProvider
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in Portal.Host
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in Provider
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in Main
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in Provider
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in Provider
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in FallbackAppearanceProvider
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in AppearanceProvider
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RNCSafeAreaView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in SafeAreaProvider
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in App
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in View
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:     in AppContainer, stack:
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: createFiberFromTypeAndProps@10553:19
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@7592:291
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: reconcileChildren@8231:62
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: beginWork$1@10260:56
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: performUnitOfWork@9855:26
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: workLoopSync@9844:40
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: renderRootSync@9827:20
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: performSyncWorkOnRoot@9605:35
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: performSyncWorkOnRoot@-1
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@6892:33
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: unstable_runWithPriority@20213:14
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl@6887:23
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: flushSyncCallbackQueue@6877:30
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: batchedUpdatesImpl@10724:103
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: batchedUpdates@6194:31
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: _receiveRootNodeIDEvent@6222:18
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: receiveEvent@6245:29
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: __callFunction@2014:35
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@1835:30
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: __guard@1968:14
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@1834:20
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@-1
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime: 
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
01-04 22:56:19.527 22500 22522 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Migration from runtime-converted svg assets to pure jsx components by using `@svgr/cli` fixed the problem. [I'm leaving a link to their very awesome playground, i case you wanna try the cli](https://react-svgr.com/playground/?native=true)

Comment: Will it impact the app size in any way?